# Can NLog v2 be used with Common.Logging

Tags: logging, nlog, common.logging

I tried using these together today, and was getting a version mismatch, as it's looking for NLog v1.

Does Common.Logging support NLog v2 yet?

If not, does anyone know if an assembly version redirect can safely be used?

Comment: did you find a solution to this - I've run into the same issue myself and am running into difficulty figuring out code changes required in Common.Logging to make it compile against NLog 2.0

Comment: @dice - not yet unfortunately, currently I'm using an earlier version of NLog

Comment: @UpTheCreek did you try assembly redirect? I checked the Common.Logging's use of NLog, it seems to be compatible with NLog2.

Answer (score 7):

You can simply do assembly redirect in app.config or web.config, and CommonLogging will just work fine with NLog2 by using NLog2 as logging framework:

```
  <runtime>
    <assemblyBinding xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v1">
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="NLog" publicKeyToken="5120e14c03d0593c" culture="neutral" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="1.0.0.0-2.0.0.0" newVersion="2.0.0.0"/>
      </dependentAssembly>
    </assemblyBinding>
  </runtime>
```

The only issue is if you want to redirect NLog message to some other logging framework using CommonLogging 2.0, then there is a compatibility issue. But that is a very unusual use case.

Comment: This does not work completely. I get error when Common.Logging.NLog tries to load `NLog.TargetWithLayout`, but the class was moved to `NLog.Targets.TargetWithLayout`so loading fails. This seems to work for many people so the next thing is to find out if using MEF breaks this.

Comment: I got this work by compiling the Common.Logging source against NLog 2.0. Changes required were quite minimal. Only change `Common.Logging.NLog.CommonLoggingTarget`s baseclass to `NLog.Targets.TargetWithLayout` and replace line 90 with `log(logger, delegate { return this.Layout.Render(logEvent); }, logEvent.Exception);`. Not a pretty solution, but works for me for now.

Answer (score 1):

If you used Nuget to get the `Common.Logging.NLog` library, the package will download Common.Logging v2.0 dependency. If you use Nuget to update `Common.Logging`, it will update it to v2.1.1.0, which will prevent the `Could not load file or assembly 'NLog, Version=1.0.0.505` error.