# Are Assembly Reference Chains Required to be Transitive?

Tags: c#, .net, .net-assembly

As an example, let's say that I am writing a library, `CommonLib` and a web application `WebUI`.  `CommonLib` references `NLog v1.0` and `WebUI` references `NLog v1.1`.

I wrote `CommonLib` ages ago and I now use it in `WebUI`, which now has a newer version of `NLog` than `CommonLib`.  `WebUI` makes calls to `CommonLib` to set up its logging.

Is this scenario at all possible?  Am I always required to update the version of `NLog` in `CommonLib`, even though the method signatures have not changed between version `1.0` and `1.1`?  Is there a workaround?

Comment: That should be possible, as long as each project references the version and not simply `NLog`. Have you tried it? Are there any problems with building or running it?

Comment: This is pretty common use case for [binding redirects](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/eftw1fys(v=vs.110).aspx).

Comment: Its *possible*, however is [a bit of a faff](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3647493/how-to-build-deploy-project-that-requires-multiple-versions-of-the-same-assembly)

Answer (score 1):

[Can NLog v2 be used with Common.Logging](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6027997/can-nlog-v2-be-used-with-common-logging) claims that you can simply redirect the older version to the newer one (for v1 to v2). Include this in your config file, matching your exact version numbers:

```
  <runtime>
    <assemblyBinding xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v1">
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="NLog" publicKeyToken="5120e14c03d0593c" culture="neutral" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="1.0.0.0" newVersion="1.1.0.0"/>
      </dependentAssembly>
    </assemblyBinding>
  </runtime>
```

[`bindingRedirect`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/eftw1fys%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) basically says, "you can go ahead and pretend that the new version will work in place of the old one".

In case that won't work, more options:

You may need to set both project's NLog Specific Version to True (in each project > References > NLog (right click, choose) Properties). With the versions specified.

Since the newest NLog will be included with your `WebUI` project build, the one that's more difficult is the old NLog used by `CommonLib`. [How the Runtime Locates Assemblies](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/yx7xezcf%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) is a good reference for various things that .Net does to try to find your assemblies.

If you can, adding it to the [GAC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Global_Assembly_Cache) is a good way to do this. In a web environment, this may not be so good of an approach, because it might not be easy to add something to the server's GAC.

[How to build/deploy project that requires multiple versions of the same assembly?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3647493/how-to-build-deploy-project-that-requires-multiple-versions-of-the-same-assembly) has more details on how you might do this in a web environment, specifically with the web.config's, e.g. yours might be this:

```
<runtime>
  <assemblyBinding xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v1">
    <dependentAssembly>
      <assemblyIdentity name="NLog" publicKeyToken="5120e14c03d0593c" />
      <codeBase version="1.0.0.505" href="bin\NLog\v1\NLog.dll" />
      <codeBase version="2.1.0.0" href="bin\NLog\v2\NLog.dll" />
    </dependentAssembly>
  </assemblyBinding>
</runtime>
```

Another way is with `Assembly.LoadFrom`. E.g. it works with the following post-build event on WebUI:

```
copy "$(SolutionDir)packages\NLog.1.0.0.505\lib\NLog.dll" "$(TargetDir)NLogv1.dll"
```

And the following line called in `CommonLib` before trying to use NLog:

```
System.Reflection.Assembly.LoadFrom("NLogv1.dll");
```